# How does the BufferedReader know which file to read?

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedreader, filereader, writer

Lets say I have

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.txt",false)) {
    BufferedReader bw=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do {
        str = bw.readLine();
        if (str.compareTo("stop") == 0) break;
        str = str + " ";
        fw.write(str);
    } while(str.compareTo("stop")!=0);
} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

How does my BufferedReader know the input stream to read? In the case of `bw.readLine()`?
Also in the case of my FileReader? Why is it then that I have to specify which file to read from? Or is it

```
String s;
//create a BufferedReader that reads a stream of characters
//FileReader Writes character Values 
try (FileReader decodeFile = new FileReader("test.txt")) {
    BufferedReader readFile=new BufferedReader(decodeFile);

    //first check to see if br has a null value
    while ((s=readFile.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am very confused about this can someone please shed some light on this? And yes I have read the documentation so I am aware of what both do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams are simply a continuous flow of data coming in. Most `Reader` class subclasses in Java declare where the stream comes from in the constructor.

1. For the first case, the `InputStreamReader` gets its input from `System.in`. `System.in` is the stream of data which is provided by the user input. Try running the java file and type a few characters and press enter at the terminal.
2. `BufferedReader` is a reader specialized in reading text efficiently. It gets the contents of the data from another stream source. In this case, the `BufferedReader(decodeFile)` signifies `decodefile` is where the `BufferedReader` reads stream data from. `decodefile` is a `FileReader` type, and `FileReader("test.txt")` signifies the file read is from a file called `test.txt`. Hence, the flow would go like this: `"test.txt"` -> `FileReader` -> `BufferedReader`

#### Updated

Looking at the documentation helps.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

PrintWriter helps write your output in a format you would like.
(By format, I mean appending a character, line flushing, formatting in general.)

On the other hand, a `FileWriter` writes stream contents to a file. Hence in this scenario, the following would would be the flow.

`String` -> `PrintWriter` -> `FileWriter` -> `"outputfile.txt"`

The string content could change like the following

"text"  -> "formatted text" -> "for", "matted ", "text" -> "formatted text"

The whole point of using streams is to chunk large amounts of data so that the process doesn't take up too much RAM (memory). Hence, chunking might (but not necessarily) happen as illustrated above.

Comment: I see, good explanation, but what if I have a PrintWriter before the FileWriter will it read both streams?

Comment: I've edited my post, although I'm not sure what you mean by "both streams"

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` doesn't really care *what* it reads, as long as it's a `Reader`. It is merely a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that adds functionality to another `Reader` implementation. What *that* `Reader` does (usually reading from a stream, but maybe from a string, or even generating random data), is of no concern to `BufferedReader` at all.

All `BufferedReader` does is to read from the wrapped `Reader` and buffer the results so that some things are achievable, e.g. reading a whole line (which requires you to read enough until you find the end of the stream or the next line break).

Comment: Ok but FileWriter is a Writer is it not?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot about my InputStreamReader

Answer (score 0):

In `BufferedReader` constructor you specify exact `Reader` with will actually reads data from input stream. as say @Joey it's just decorator

In your example you will read from std input stream and in second case from exact file

Comment: Oh so, the BufferedReader, reads any InputStreamReader, so in the case of the FileWriter, it would reader the input Stream, and lets say i created a PrintWriter, It would also read the input Stream correc?

Comment: you mess up with FileWriter. 
You are reading from `new InputStreamReader(System.in)` and write to test.txt file. You are not using FileWriter for BufferedReader

Comment: Well then how is it writing to my file? If I did not have a fileWriter how would it know the location to write to?

Comment: yes, in fileWriter you should specify output location but doesn't matter from which place you got data. in FileWriter you write some string which you get from somewhere. here from `new InputStreamReader(System.in)`, but it's not important actually